# Quiero hacer un toggle switch language?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer un toggle switch language para dos idiomas y mi segmento de codigo

El detalle es el siguien estoy haciendolo con .pug y no se mucho de sass, he instalado sass al pie de la letra me compila de sass a css correctamente, me aparece el toggle switch con la carita pero cuando doy click no hace el movimiento o el change

que estoy haciendo mal?
Me he guiado de esto
https://codepen.io/mburnette/pen/reRKNx

```js
$('.wrap').on('click', function(e){
 $(this).toggleClass('funny');
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
scss
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

body {
 background: #eee;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5em 0;
}

.wrap-text {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: 0 1em;
 font-size: 2em;
 color: #333;
}

.wrap {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 background: #ddd;
 height: 10em;
 width: 24em;
 border-radius: 10em;
 padding: 1em;
 cursor: pointer;
 
 &.funny {
  background: #069;
 }
}

.toggle {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #fff;
 height: 8em;
 width: 8em;
 border-radius: 100%;
 position: relative;
 
 &:before,
 &:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 25%;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
 }

 .active &:before,
 .active &:after {
  animation: slidetoboring 0.4s linear;
 }

 &:before {
  left: 25%;
 }

 &:after {
  right: 25%;
 }
 
 .funny & {
  margin-left: 14em;

  &:before,
  &:after {
   background: #069;
   animation: slidetofunny 0.4s linear;
  }
 }
}

.mouth {
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 1.5em;
 right: 1.5em;
 height: 0.5em;
 background: #ddd;
 border-radius: 1em;

 .active & {
  animation: slidetoboring 0.4s linear;
 }
 
 .funny & {
  height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 1em 1em 10em 10em;
  background: #069;
  animation: slidetofunny 0.4s;
  top: 55%;
 }
}

@keyframes slidetofunny {
 0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
 50% { transform: translateX(100%); }
 51% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
 100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@keyframes slidetoboring {
 0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
 50% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
 51% { transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}
```

```html
<span class="wrap-text">boring</span>
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="toggle">
  <span class="mouth"></span>
 </div>
</div>
<span class="wrap-text">funny</span>
```

Comment: Lo único que tienes que hacer es incluir la libreria de jquery:                  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Lastima que no lo pusiste como respuesta @DanielB.Alzate

Answer (score 1):

En Codepen esta haciendo uso de jquery, lo puedes ver aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que te falta es incluirlo antes de código javascript:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

el resultado quedaría igual

```js
$(".wrap").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("funny");
  $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

```css
        *, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5em 0;
}

.wrap-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #333;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 10em;
  width: 24em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrap.funny {
  background: #069;
}

.toggle {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  height: 8em;
  width: 8em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.toggle:before, .toggle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 25%;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.active .toggle:before, .active .toggle:after {
  animation: slidetoboring 0.4s linear;
}
.toggle:before {
  left: 25%;
}
.toggle:after {
  right: 25%;
}
.funny .toggle {
  margin-left: 14em;
}
.funny .toggle:before, .funny .toggle:after {
  background: #069;
  animation: slidetofunny 0.4s linear;
}

.mouth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 1.5em;
  right: 1.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.active .mouth {
  animation: slidetoboring 0.4s linear;
}
.funny .mouth {
  height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 1em 1em 10em 10em;
  background: #069;
  animation: slidetofunny 0.4s;
  top: 55%;
}

@keyframes slidetofunny {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@keyframes slidetoboring {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="wrap-text">boring</span>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="toggle">
        <span class="mouth"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="wrap-text">funny</span>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```